# npm install giving error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: npm, blockchain, npm-install, truffle

I had cloned a truffle project from GitHub, while doing `npm install` am getting following error:

```
npm ERR! command /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/17.3.0/bin/node /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/Users/rohit12242/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! The git reference could not be found
npm ERR! npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects checkout 4.0
npm ERR! npm ERR! error: pathspec '4.0' did not match any file(s) known to git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I installed node version 11 and fixed this error

Comment: how do you "install node version 11"?